# Extract all matches to neighboring column cell in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, re2

**Question**: looking for Google Sheets regex that captures all instances of a string between `[t- ]` and outputs to the neighboring column cell as an array, or some other delimiter between matches.

For the following string, I'm trying to extract all instances of text between `[t- ]`.

A1:

> Lorem Ipsum **[t- is simply]** dummy text of the **[t- printing]** and typesetting [c- industry], so [d- it would make] sense that

Expected Output is an array of all occurrences in a single column:

B1:

> [is simply, printing]

Or output could be any delimiter of match occurrences

> is simply | printing

Trying the following with a single text within `[t- ]` works fine, but for multiple instances it extracts everything between open `[t-` of first occurrence and `]` of last occurrence:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\[t- (.*)\]")`

Leading to:

> is simply]! dummy text of the [t- printing

I've also tried multiple capture groups, but this only works if I'm sure there's only two instances of text between `[t- ]`— there could be `n` instances per row. Also it doesn't output results to an arrary in one column, but spreads across multiple columns:

`=regexextract(A1, "(\[t- (.*)\]).*(\[t- (.*)\])" )`

---

**EDIT**: I've received a couple answers with Regex that works for other tools/languages (e.g., PHP or Javascript) but not Google Sheets. Here's the [Google Sheets Regex Syntax](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YFyOFSm7P4pssBMY7qTrWinz2SDMZW1KUnkmePDORS0/preview).

**EDIT 2**: The above sample string has other text inside brackets marked with other letters, e.g., `[c- industry]` and `[d- it would make]`. These should **not** be included. Only texted in `[t- ]` (with a "t-") should be returned.

Comment: Try `\[t-([^]]*)\]`. You can check and get an explanation here https://regex101.com/r/iemQDb/1.

Comment: @AndreiOdegov this only gets the first occurrence

Comment: what about REGEXREPLACE and the `(?:^|\])[^\[]*(?:\[t-|$)` regex? check here https://regex101.com/r/WwFjcy/1.

Comment: @AndreiOdegov this works better, but this also gets text inside brackets with other characters, e.g., `[c- ]`, or `[d- ]`. It needs to only get texts within `[t- ]` and ignore replacing text when there's other brackets (like `[c- ]` or `[d- ]`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187816/discussion-between-growler-and-andrei-odegov).

Comment: Who is the author of the "Google Sheets Regex Syntax"? At the bottom of it there is link to a blank page.

Comment: `@Growler`, all the same REGEXREPLACE, but with new regex `^.*?\[t-|(?<=\[t-).*?\K\].*?(?:\[t-|$)`. Check it here https://regex101.com/r/WwFjcy/2.

Comment: @AndreiOdegov thanks but are you not testing in google sheets? The syntax is invalid.

Comment: @Onyambu what do you mean? That doesn't look like valid syntax for Google Sheets. How would it look in the entire formula?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar to the technique used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45463802),

- `REGEXREPLACE` all `[t-.*]` to `(.*)`
- Provide the resulting expression from above as the regex to `REGEXEXTRACT`
- `\Q..\E` is used to escape other characters

  ```
  =REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\Q"&REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\[t-[^]]+\]","\\E(.*)\\Q")&"\E")
  ```

---

Alternatively, With just `REGEXREPLACE` to delimit,

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(^|\])(.*?)(\[t-|$)","$1|$3")
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(^|\])(.*?)(\[t-|$)","$1|$3"),"|")
```

Replace all characters `.*` that

- Start with `]` or start of string `^`
- End with `[t-` or end of string `$`

with `]|[t-`

Comment: These are great - they work for all cases except when two `[t- ]` are next to each other with space and without space. E.g., when string is `[t- hello] [t- world]`. You end up with `[t- hello] [t-` in one column cell as match, and `world]` in the next. When string is `[t- hello][t- world]` (no space) you get `[t- hello][t- world]` as single match in cell

Comment: @Growler The second regex works fine in both cases and the output is exactly the same as first with `split`. The first one didn't work because of the greedy `(.*)`. If we change it to `"\\E(\\Q$0\\E)\\Q"`, it works.

Comment: Thank you! This works great. It's really too bad `regexextract` doesn't have a greedy option to extract all instances

Comment: @Growler, Compared to excel, having regex in spreadsheet itself is a boon.

Answer (score 3):

**bulletproof solution:**

```
="["&JOIN(", ", ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(
 QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, "[")), "]"), 
 "select Col1 where Col1 contains 't- '", 0), 
 "t- ", "")))&"]"
```

[image]

### __________________________________________________________

```
=JOIN(" | ", ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(
 QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, "[")), "]"), 
 "select Col1 where Col1 contains 't- '", 0), 
 "t- ", "")))
```

[image]